# как сделать динамический счетчик?

Tags: flutter, dart, counter

делаю корзину на flutter.
Но, столкнулся с проблемой. По задумке, юзер может добавить количество товара из корзины. Но, из-за того, что я использую одну переменную, то счетчик увеличивается/уменьшается везде сразу. Как это исправить?
PS: Я не могу знать, сколько будет товара, его добавляет сам пользователь

Вот мой код -
Сохранение состояния -

```
int value = 1;

  inc() {
    setState(() {
      value++;
    });
  }
  dec() {
    setState(() {
      value--;
    });
  }
```

Отображение -

```
Expanded(
                            child: ListView.builder(
                          controller: controller,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          itemCount: HomeBody.shoppingBasketHeader!.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            if (index < HomeBody.shoppingBasketHeader!.length)  {
                              return Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black))
                                ),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Container(
                                          width: 150,
                                          child: Image.network('http://10.0.2.2:1337${HomeBody.shoppingBasketImage?[index]}'),
                                        )

                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Container(
                                          width: 200,
                                          child: Column(
                                            children: [
                                              Container(
                                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                                child: Text(' ${HomeBody.shoppingBasketHeader?[index]}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),),
                                              ),

                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                          width: 200,
                                          child: Column(
                                            children: [
                                              Container(
                                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                                child: Text(' ${HomeBody.shoppingBasketPrice?[index]}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),),
                                              ),

                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: [
                                            Container(
                                              child: IconButton(onPressed: () {inc();}, icon: Icon(Icons.add)),
                                            ),
                                            Container(
                                              child: Text('$value'),
                                            ),
                                            Container(
                                              child: IconButton(onPressed: () {dec();}, icon: Icon(Icons.remove)),
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),

                                  ],
                                ),
                              );

                            } else {
                              return Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 10),
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text('Список полностью загружен!'),
                                ),
                              );
                            }
                          }
                      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Для вашего примера могу предложить решение c `ValueNotifier`, который позволяет перестраивать не весь виджет, а лишь ту часть, которую вам понадобится обновлять.

1. Генерируем список с объектами `ValueNotifier` перед методом `Widget build()`:

```
final valueNotifiers = List.generate(
  HomeBody.shoppingBasketHeader!.length,
  (_) => ValueNotifier<int>(1),
);
```

2. Контент, который должны перестраивать, оборачиваем виджетом `ValueListenableBuilder`:

```
ValueListenableBuilder<int>(
 valueListenable: valueNotifiers[index],
 builder: (context, counter, child) {
   return Text('$counter');
 },
)
```

3. Теперь `inc` и `dec` будут выглядеть так:

```
inc(int index) {
  counterNotifiers[index].value++;
}

dec(int index) {
  counterNotifiers[index].value--;
}
```

4. Не забываем уничтожить наши объекты:

```
@override
void dispose() {
  controller.dispose();
  for (final notifier in counterNotifiers) {
    notifier.dispose();
  }
  super.dispose();
}
```

Полный пример может выглядеть так:

```
class BasketPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const BasketPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BasketPage> createState() => _BasketPageState();
}

class _BasketPageState extends State<BasketPage> {
  final controller = ScrollController();

  inc(int index) {
    counterNotifiers[index].value++;
  }

  dec(int index) {
    counterNotifiers[index].value--;
  }

  final counterNotifiers = List.generate(
    HomeBody.shoppingBasketHeader!.length,
    (_) => ValueNotifier<int>(1),
  );

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    for (final notifier in counterNotifiers) {
      notifier.dispose();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Корзина'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        controller: controller,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        itemCount: HomeBody.shoppingBasketHeader!.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index < HomeBody.shoppingBasketHeader!.length) {
            return Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
              decoration:
                  const BoxDecoration(border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black))),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 150,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 200,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                              child: Text(
                                ' ${HomeBody.shoppingBasketHeader?[index]}',
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 200,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                              child: Text(
                                ' ${HomeBody.shoppingBasketPrice?[index]}',
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            child: IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                inc(index);
                              },
                              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: ValueListenableBuilder<int>(
                              valueListenable: counterNotifiers[index],
                              builder: (context, value, child) {
                                return Text('$value');
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                dec(index);
                              },
                              icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Список полностью загружен!'),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```